# $5\mid n\iff5\mid n^2$, proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I have to prove that for $n\in\Bbb Z$ 
$$5\mid n\iff 5\mid n^2$$
Could you give me please a hint how to do this? Like induction, or an indirect proof. It is easy to explain that this is always right, but a bit difficult to prove it mathematically.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint 1: use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Hint 2: when is $n^2$ congruent to $0$ mod $5$?

Comment: One direction is easy.

Comment: for an elementary proof that $5\,|\,n^2\implies 5\,|\,n$, write $n=5k+r$ for $r\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.  Show, case by case, that $5\,|\,n^2\implies r=0$.

Comment: @lulu thank you very much, that makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $5\mid n$ then $n=5k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ which means $n^2=25k^2=5\cdot 5k^2$ therefore $5\mid n^2$. For the other direction assume that $5\mid n^2$. A square modulo $5$ is congruent to either $0$ or $1$ or $4$ which can be used to show the other direction. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

*Hints*:

- $(\Longrightarrow)$ If $a\mid b$ then $a\mid bc$.
- $(\Longleftarrow)$ 5 is a prime number; use Euclid's lemma.

Comment: Can I use Euclid's lemma for the first hint?

Comment: @Blnpwr Ung... the first hint doesn't even need Euclid's lemma, it's a fundamental property of divisibility.

Answer (score 2):

For the forward implication: observe that if $5|n$ there is an integer $k$ such that $n=5k.$

For the backward implication: suppose $5|n^2$ and $5\not|n.$ Then $n=5k+r$ for some integer $r$ which is not a multiple of $5.$ Consider the square for cases $r=\pm 1, \pm2$ separately and derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

One more attempt:

$\Rightarrow:$

$5|n$, then $n=5r$, then $n^2 = 5×(5×r^2)$, hence $5|n^2.$

$\Leftarrow:$

$5|n^2.$

Euclid's Lemma:

If a prime $p$ divides $ab$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divided $b.$

$\rightarrow:$

$5|n×n$ implies $5|n.$